# How to make DataTable horizontally scrollable on Desktop?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, desktop

I am attempting to make a DataTable that is both horizontally and vertically scrollable. With the code below, vertical scrolling is working fine on both desktop and mobile, but horizontal scrolling only works on mobile and not on desktop. Note the SingleChildScrollView with scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, which prevents the table from producing errors for overflowing off the screen but does not allow for horizontal scrolling on desktop. Moving the horizontal SingleChildScrollView from where it is in the below code to directly after the vertical SingleChildScrollView does not cause any changes.

(P.S. don't worry about the column with one child, I've omitted commented out widgets that aren't relevant to the question)

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          _itemTable([{
            "test1": "verylongvalueverylongvalueverylongvalue", 
            "test2": "verylongvalueverylongvalueverylongvalue", 
            "test3": "verylongvalueverylongvalueverylongvalue", 
            "test4": "verylongvalueverylongvalueverylongvalue", 
            "test5": "verylongvalueverylongvalueverylongvalue", 
            "test6": "verylongvalueverylongvalueverylongvalue"
          }])
        ]
      )
    )
  );

  Widget _itemTable(List data) {

    var headers = data[0].keys;

    List<DataRow> rows = [];

    data.forEach(
      (item) => rows.add(
        DataRow(
          cells: 
            headers.map<DataCell>(
              (String hdr) => DataCell(Text(item[hdr].toString()))
            ).toList()
        )
      )
    );

    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: DataTable(
          showCheckboxColumn: false,
          columns: headers.map<DataColumn>((h) => DataColumn(label: Text(h))).toList(),
          rows: rows
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: I tried using a ListView as well, it had the same effect as the SingleChildScrollView. This is the return statement I used for the ListView version:

```
return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 49 * (rows.length + 1),
    child: ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: [DataTable(
        showCheckboxColumn: false,
        columns: headers.map<DataColumn>((h) => DataColumn(label: Text(h))).toList(),
        rows: rows
      )]
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Try to use [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html)

Comment: @YoussefHegab I tried it, it had the same effect as the SingleChildScrollView